# NSDateFormatter format date by year and month

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I tried to set NSDateFormatter for year, like this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSLog(@"**> %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012"]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

But it prints: **> 2011-12-31 22:00:00 +0000

Maybe someone could help me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the timezone difference between UTC (GMT) and your time zone (you're probably in GMT+2). NSDate is in UTC by default. That's why [NSDate date] can deviate from the local time.

The following code should output Jan 1, 2012:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy zzz"];
NSLog(@"**> %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012 GMT"]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

or

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSLog(@"NSDate : %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012"]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are from +02:00 timezone. As NSDate always gives the time in GMT timezone, instead of printing `2012-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` , it is printing the above value which is the time in  GMT timezone.

**Edit:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSLog(@"NSDate : %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012"]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: but if i want to print just 2012